# Need to See which files have changed in 24 hours and send anemail (Shell Script)

Tags: shell, ssh

I need a shell script which I can schedule as a Cron job. It will point to a directory and recursively check each PHP file to see if it has changed in the last 24 hours, and write that to a log file and e-mail the log file to us every night.

So the script will do the following:

1. Scan A Directory recursively forall php files that have changed in 24 hours (home/user/httpdocs)
2. Log them into a file (/tmp/diff-2012-05-18.log)
3. E-Mail the logfile to ane-mail address -

It should be something which is easy to test out before we automate it.

Any ideas on how to do this in an efficient manner, i have a method that does SOME of it, but its taxing on the server. -

Comment: Are you looking to find files that you or your colleagues have updated, or are you looking to find files that may have been modified maliciously by an intruder? Eduardo Ivanec's answer is ideal for the first case but inadequate for the second.

Answer (score 2):

For the modified files part:

```
find /path/to/dir -iname '*php' -mtime -1 > /tmp/diff-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
```

Then:

```
mail user@example.com < /tmp/diff-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
```

The ideal thing would be to create a variable `$OUTPUT` with the right date first, in case the first command takes too long and finishes the next day. So, putting it all together:

```
OUTPUT=/tmp/diff-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
find /path/to/dir -iname '*php' -mtime -1 > $OUTPUT
mail user@example.com < $OUTPUT
```

Alternatively if you want to get a little more sophisticated and are aiming at a one liner, you can use `tee` to both save the list to a file and mail it at the same time (sort of):

```
find /path/to/dir -iname '*php' -mtime -1 | tee /tmp/diff-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log | mail user@example.com
```